# SCCM 2012 R2 | Windows Updates Installation Stuck

Tags: sccm, system-center

When i install updates via Task Sequence, the deployments gets stuck.

1. I have a collection with members
2. I have deployed monthly updates and set the Deployment setting purpose to "Available"
3. Now i have a TS to install updates, this TS, install all the updates which are available and required for the machine, Condition is set to "Install + Reboot"
4. The installation of all updates happens at correct time
5. Once all the updates are installed, the TS "application" deployment is stuck at installing.. Since this is stuck, it does not allow the machines in the collection to reboot

### Image:

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: It seems unconventional to use a task sequence to install updates.  I think you might be doing this the hard way.  I suspect using SCCM's built-in "Software Updates" feature would be much smoother.  To troubleshoot the what's happening, you're going to need to find the right logs on the client and determine how far the SCCM client got through the executing the task sequence.  Use CMTrace to review the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Solution for this, There were few MS updates who execution time is more than the actual. And these MS Updates were stuck at installing status, due to this the TS of update deployment also got stuck.